# How can i fix Scroll bar goes under naigation bar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, navbar

i have a problem where my navigation bar go over the scroll bar making scroll bar the bottom guy:
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlhtD.png)
is there and thing i can do about it ?
here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-style">
<nav>
<img src="images/logo_3.png" height="60px" width="215px">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="#">About</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  font-size:100%;
  overflow-y:hidden;
 }

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
   }

html, body {
  position:relative;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  height:100%;
   }

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    #main-style{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Hope you guy can help me out Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you see about removing some of the extra CSS so it's a bit clearer where your issues are?

Comment: As you wish. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**i think your problem in overflow , maybe that will be work :**

```
<nav>
    <img src="images/logo_3.png" height="60px" width="215px">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">About</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

css :

```
nav {
     display:block;
     overflow: visibility !important;
}
html, body {
  position:relative;
  //overflow-x:hidden;
  height:100%;
   }
```